# How to return json result on web api asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

im starting learning C# and I create a web api on asp.net, but I don't find a way to return a json with a route "pokemon/hello", im trying to return:

{
"pokemon": "hello world"
}

I tried with a IActionResult but I have no result

thanks for helping

I created a controller, and tried to find with the code of WeatherForecastController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a PokemonModel as Response:

```
public class PokemonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult<PokemonModel> Pokemon()
    {
        PokemonModel pokemon = new PokemonModel { Pokemon = "charizard" };
        return pokemon;
    }
}

// .../Models/
public class PokemonModel
{
    public string Pokemon { get; set; }
}
```